# Can we download a S3 file using javascript in browser?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-javascript-sdk

I need to download a S3 file(in GBs) using javascript in a browser. Please let me know if it is possible and if there are any article with the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to download the file using the pre signed URL.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Steps:
1) Create a pre signed URL using the bucket, key name and the credential(Cognito).
2) Download the file using the pre signed URL. For downloading file using URL, We can find a lot of article online.